# how to set variable on window batch file for private use only

Tags: batch-file, window

For the following simple test batch file on window, why? the last a is 8  not 100 by set command 
I try use setlocal  that doesn't solve the issue. Why ? And last question how to let my batch file not read the window system environment variable which may be  same variable name as the one I am using in my batch file ? I just want to use "set" in batch for setting variables for private  use within the batch file. Please advise

```
    @echo off 
    set a=3
    echo %a%
    echo -------Start-------------------------
    set a=8
    echo %a%
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%F in ('path') do (
    REM setlocal enableextensions 
    REM setlocal disableextensions 
    REM setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    REM setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    set a=100
    echo %a%
    REM endlocal
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax for delayed expansion

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo !a!
```